# General check of missing semicolon

Tags: perl

As a Perl beginner I am sometimes getting compilation errors and have to search a lot to find it. In the end it is just a missing semicolon at the end of a line. Some syntax errors with missing semicolon are checked by Perl but not in general. Is there a way to get this check?

edit:

I know about Perl::Critic but can't use it atm. And I don't know if it checks for missing semicolon in general.

Comment: This is really something you ought to be doing in your editor, not at runtime; thus, it's really more of a tool-specific question than a language-specific question. What editor/IDE do you use?

Comment: (In Vim, for instance, you could just do a search for `[^;{}]$`, which would highlight all end-of-line characters that aren't braces or semicolons.)

Comment: I am using vim, thanks for that hint. But for longs scripts which are well documented I have to search for a while. Because I usually don't end my comments with ;

Comment: Why do you have long, well-documented scripts that are missing semicolons all over the place? You can try leaving out lines that start with a comment using `^[^#].*[^;{}]$`; if you want exclude any lines with comments and are willing to risk missing lines that have a `#` in them for other reasons, try `^[^#]*[^;{}]$`.

Comment: I am just asking in case my scripts get longer and I don't see a problem in making commentaries. The hint to skip commentaries isn't working for me.

Comment: What's the behavior you're observing?

Answer (score 2):

Because semicolons actually mean something in Perl and aren't just there for decoration, it's not possible for any tool (even the Perl interpreter itself) to know in every case whether you actually meant to leave off the semi-colon or not. Thus, there's no general-case answer to your question; you'll just need to go through your code and make sure it's correct.

As mentioned in my comments, there are various tricks you can try with your editor to expedite the process of finding potentially-incorrect lines; you must, however, either examine and fix these by hand or risk introducing new problems.

Comment: Yes of course you are correct that there can't be a general rule. I was searching for a way in minimising the search and your tips are really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax check is [`perl -c`](http://p3rl.org/run#%2a-c%2a), but that's no different than attempting to run the program outright. Due to its flexible/undecidable syntax, one cannot generally do what you want. That's the downside of comfort and expressiveness.

Upgrade to the latest stable Perl, the parser's error messages got better/more exact over the last years and will correctly recognise many circumstances of a missing semicolon.

Rule of thumb that works for many parsers/other languages: if the error makes no sense, look a couple of lines before.

Comment: Yes this rule of thumb is what I was expecting too and I guess every experienced Perl user will do so. I just have to get this in my memory ;)

Answer (score 1):

`use diagnostics;` usually gives you a nice hint, same as `use warnings;`. Try to keep a consistent coding style, check [perlstyle](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlstyle.html).
Also you can use [Perl::Critic online](http://perlcritic.com).

Also as general advice learn how to use packages and modules, try to group code into subs and study the syntax of arrays, lists and hashes. A common mistake is forgetting the `;` after an anonymous hashref assignment:

```
my $hashref = { a => 5, b => 10};
```

Comment: I am always using `use strict` and `use warnings` but `use diagnostics` is a new one for me. Thx.